# proving a theorem on bijective functions composition

Tags: functions

I've got a theorem I need to prove, if it's true, or disprove if it's not. However, I don't know how.

This is the problem:

Let $f,g,h$ be bijective functions. Then $ f=g \Rightarrow f \circ h = g \circ h $.

In other words, I want to prove, that doing this:

$
f=g \qquad / \circ h \\
f \circ h = g \circ h \\
$

Is mathematically correct.
Maybe it is also possible to prove this using group theory?
Thank you for any answers.

Comment: How is the domain and range for these functions defined? If they are in the group $Sym(X)$, we can apply group theory. Otherwise your claim is obvious anyway.

Comment: How do you check whether two functions are equal? (Your claim is simply $f \circ h = f \circ h$.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde How do you apply group theory to this?

Comment: @QiZhu If $f,g,h\in G$ for a group $G$, then $f=g$ implies $fh=gh$, since we may multiply an equation in $G$ with any group element.